# Unpolarized Capacitors in place of Polarized ones

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor, ceramic

I have found some projects of interest, and on them there are generally a *polarized* capacitor in the range of 10 multiple (0.1uf, 1f, 10uf, 100uf, etc), and I do not know why I ordered a lot of *polarized* capacitors in the 47 range (0.47uf, 4.7uf, 47uf, 470uf and 4700uf), but *unpolarized* ones of the 10 multiples range.

If I place a unpolarized capacitor in place of a polarized one, can it discharge the wrong way, and burn my circuit?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Note that high-power ultrasonic frequencies can burn up most capacitors except polypropylene.

Answer (score 1):

It will not damage your circuit, but there are many other characteristics of capacitors that are important to a circuit working:  voltage rating, current rating, equivalent series resistance, dc bias derating, etc.

Comment: I knew (or know, this doesn't matters now) about the voltage and current rating of the capacitors. Based on some "wish analyzes" I choose to pick 50v ones, and the amperage rating I don't remember now. But, what is equivalent series resistance and dc bias derating?

Comment: Some types of capacitors (MLCC ceramics for one) exhibit a reduced capacitance with increased DC voltage across the capacitor.  This reduction can be significant.  Equivalent Series Resistance (ESR) is one of the three primary parasitic effects in capacitors.  Leakage is like a resistor in parallel with the capacitor.  ESL (equivalent series inductance) is like an inductor in series with the capacitor.  ESR is like a resistor in series with the capacitor.  The ESR will limit the current flow into or out of the capacitor which can significantly impact the behavior of circuits.

Answer (score 0):

No, no such thing will happen. But you have to be careful for another reason:

A schematic will specify capacitor types, e.g. aluminium, tantalum, paper, polypropylen, polyester, ceramics of certain types. It will also tell if there are special ratings to follow, e.g. for ESL and ESR, and X and Y safety features.

If there's nothing marked in the schematic, you can assume all unmarked unpolarized caps are either ceramic or polypropylen, and all unmarked polarized caps are aluminium ones. You can drop in polypropylen caps for small aluminium ones usually.

Answer (score 0):

You may not know that there are millions of different capacitors with a dozen different specifications which may or may not matter in any given circuit.

Even in electrolytics and ceramics there a dozen different families which tradeoff different parameters such as;

Cost, Size, Voltage rating, tan delta @120Hz, ESR, ripple current , rated voltage, leakage current, temp. vs accelerated short life rating. e.g. 1000hrs at 105'C, self resonanct frequency,  capacitance vs V vs 'C and shape, aspect ratio, value AND  tolerance.

It depends on the application demands or specs for impedance(f), current (rms) and Vpk/rated ratio, leakage equiv R, ripple voltage, f attenuation. etc

Will it work? to do what?

For electrolytics; there are General Purpose polar, non-polar, low ESR, ultra low ESR, high temp, ultra high temp, high ripple current.

So for general purpose applications, no problem.

Due to impedance Z(f)=1/(2pi*fC) and Self Resonant frequency (SRF),  some designs limit the useful range of e-caps to a few decades in f, and ESR dops with rising uF so SRF also rises with smaller uF ( family sensitive).

Thus it was common in power filters to use 0.01(ceramic)//1uF/100uF 0.047/4.7//100uF//1mF depending on design and surge currents and rate of dI/dt.  There is no one solution to all problems.